# r color: how to get color values from a scale_color_continuous

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

For example, there is a numeric variable array like (1.3,4.5,5.4,3.7,2.8....). When we use ggplot and scale_color_continuous, we can get a color bar for it. How can I get the values of this bar so that I can use the same color values to somewhere else?
I mean, I want to put these color values to a data.frame as a column.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the 'scales' package.

Comment: Thanks guys. I found one method to do it too.